# How to get complete data of folders, sub folders, issues, clashes and employees of forge bim360

Tags: autodesk-bim360

Can I get complete folders and subfolders information of bim360 data from forge to post in the dashboard? I have a requirement that is within the dashboard I have to show complete folder data and issues data and employees and clashes data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and copy-paste some code you've already tried and rephrase the question asking about why it doesn't work for example. Stackoverflow is not a code generator service.

Answer (score 0):

To get folder structure, Here are the steps.

- Call [GET hubs/:hub_id/projects/:project_id/topFolders](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/) to get the highest level folders the user can access for a given project.
- Call [GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) repeatedly until there is no folder appeared in the response.

Here is the code snippet from the [learn forge tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/hubs/readme):

```js
async function getFolders(hubId, projectId, oauthClient, credentials, res) {
    const projects = new ProjectsApi();
    const folders = await projects.getProjectTopFolders(hubId, projectId, oauthClient, credentials);
    res.json(folders.body.data.map((item) => {
        return createTreeNode(
            item.links.self.href,
            item.attributes.displayName == null ? item.attributes.name : item.attributes.displayName,
            item.type,
            true
        );
    }));
}

async function getFolderContents(projectId, folderId, oauthClient, credentials, res) {
    const folders = new FoldersApi();
    const contents = await folders.getFolderContents(projectId, folderId, {}, oauthClient, credentials);
    const treeNodes = contents.body.data.map((item) => {
        var name = (item.attributes.name == null ? item.attributes.displayName : item.attributes.name);
        if (name !== '') { // BIM 360 Items with no displayName also don't have storage, so not file to transfer
            return createTreeNode(
                item.links.self.href,
                name,
                item.type,
                true
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
    res.json(treeNodes.filter(node => node !== null));
}

// ref: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/datamanagement.js
```

For issues, check these resources:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-issues-api-sample-nodejs
- https://github.com/xiaodongliang/bim360-node.js-issues.api

For clash, you may check this sample: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashissue

To get account users and project users, you may make use of the admin API:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/

Comment: how to count number of "Revit" files in a folder

Comment: [GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/)`?filter[fileType]=rvt`